# Win32 TBBUTTON fsStyle values do not fit?

Tags: c, winapi

TBBUTTON has the following structure:

```
typedef struct _TBBUTTON {
    int iBitmap;
    int idCommand;
    BYTE fsState;
    BYTE fsStyle;
#ifdef _WIN64
    BYTE bReserved[6];          // padding for alignment
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    BYTE bReserved[2];          // padding for alignment
#endif
    DWORD_PTR dwData;
    INT_PTR iString;
} TBBUTTON, NEAR* PTBBUTTON, *LPTBBUTTON;
typedef const TBBUTTON *LPCTBBUTTON;
```

Now if you see, `fsStyle` is a `BYTE` (range 0-255); however, the values you can pass are:

```
#define TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS        0x0100
#define TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE        0x0200
#define TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG         0x0400
#define TBSTYLE_FLAT            0x0800
#define TBSTYLE_LIST            0x1000
#define TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE     0x2000
#define TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP    0x4000
#define TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT     0x8000
```

None of these can fit into a `BYTE`; and, quite correctly, the compiler gives a warning (`warning C4305: '=': truncation from 'int' to 'BYTE'`) when using for example:

```
TBBUTTON button;
button.fsStyle = TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS;
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-and-button-styles) does not mention anything about this, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'style flag' constants you have listed (`TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS` thru `TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT`) are window styles **for a toolbar itself**, not for any buttons it contains.

In the [MSDN document you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-and-button-styles), the sentence, *"A toolbar button can have a combination of the following styles."*, comes ***after*** the list of those styles and refers to the list/box with the `BTNS_AUTOSIZE` thru `TBSTYLE_SEP` styles, which have values in the range `0x0000` thru `0x0080` – and these **do** fit in the `fsStyle` (`BYTE`) field of the `TBBUTTON` structure.

Here's the section of the "CommCtrl.h" header that defines these:

```c
#define BTNS_BUTTON     TBSTYLE_BUTTON      // 0x0000
#define BTNS_SEP        TBSTYLE_SEP         // 0x0001
#define BTNS_CHECK      TBSTYLE_CHECK       // 0x0002
#define BTNS_GROUP      TBSTYLE_GROUP       // 0x0004
#define BTNS_CHECKGROUP TBSTYLE_CHECKGROUP  // (TBSTYLE_GROUP | TBSTYLE_CHECK)
#define BTNS_DROPDOWN   TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN    // 0x0008
#define BTNS_AUTOSIZE   TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE    // 0x0010; automatically calculate the cx of the button
#define BTNS_NOPREFIX   TBSTYLE_NOPREFIX    // 0x0020; this button should not have accel prefix
#define BTNS_SHOWTEXT   0x0040              // ignored unless TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS is set
#define BTNS_WHOLEDROPDOWN  0x0080          // draw drop-down arrow, but without split arrow section
```

Comment: Might want to add the following from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-and-button-styles): *"For Shell version 4.72 and earlier, both window and button style flags had the form `TBSTYLE_XXX`. [...] For version 5.80 and later, all button styles have the form `BTNS_XXX`."*

Comment: Now this makes sense (unlike documentation, which could be more straightforward). Thanks.